# Determining if two instances are the same except for two properties

Tags: c#, object, comparison, equals

I have a class with ten properties, and am looking for objects that have the same values in these properties except for two specific properties.

I'm thinking of extending a base class which has the eight properties that I want to compare, and then extend this base class, calling the base `Equals` method?

What would be the least code-intensive way of determining this?

Comment: Creating a hierarchy of objects whith the *sole* purpose of a comparison is IMHO an overkill. If they share some other behavior / implementation commonalities then it might be reasonable, otherwise I'd just implement a static method (extension or not, doesn't really matter) that simply returns a bool indicating if all 8 properties of two given instances are the same.

Comment: It figured I'd overlook the most obvious solution! You want to see some of my variable names too! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you wish to compare two instances of a custom class for value equality (that is two objects with the same value or values) rather than reference quality (that two object references refer to the same underlying object), you must take this into account in the design of the object. There is a [pattern you can follow to do this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd183755.aspx). In a nutshell, it involves implementing the `System.IEquatable<T>` interface, which defines a method with the signature `bool Equals(MyClass other)`. You implement this method to return `true` when `other` has the same 'value' is `this` object. Here is a basic example ofsimple object that has 4 properties that determine its value equality:

```
class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    public int ImportantProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int ImportantProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int ImportantProperty3 { get; set; }
    public int ImportantProperty4 { get; set; }
    public int NonImportantProperty { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        return
            (!Object.ReferenceEquals(this, null)) &&
            (this.ImportantProperty1 == other.ImportantProperty1) &&
            (this.ImportantProperty2 == other.ImportantProperty2) &&
            (this.ImportantProperty3 == other.ImportantProperty3) &&
            (this.ImportantProperty4 == other.ImportantProperty4);
    }
}
```

With the above code you will be able to do the following:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass() { };
MyClass b = new MyClass() { };
if (a.Equals(b))
    Console.WriteLine("a and b are equal");
```

This is the bare minimum. However, as noted in the linked article, you might want to consider the following optimizations:

1. Override the `virtual Object.Equals(Object)` method so that calls the type specific Equals method. This will allow you to compare `MyClass` with objects of other types:

   ```
   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       return this.Equals(obj as MyClass);
   }
   ```
2. Add to `bool Equals(MyClass)` method a check to see if `other` references the same object as `this`:

   ```
       public bool Equals(MyClass other)
       {
           if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
               return true;    

           return
               (!Object.ReferenceEquals(this, null)) &&
               (this.ImportantProperty1 == other.ImportantProperty1) &&
               (this.ImportantProperty2 == other.ImportantProperty2) &&
               (this.ImportantProperty3 == other.ImportantProperty3) &&
               (this.ImportantProperty4 == other.ImportantProperty4);
       }
   ```
3. Override `Object.GetHashCode()` method so that two objects that have value equality produce the same hash code. This is the pattern I use when implement this method in this kind of scenario:

   ```
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       unchecked {
           int hash = 17;
           hash = hash * 23 + ImportantProperty1.GetHashCode();
           hash = hash * 23 + ImportantProperty2.GetHashCode();
           hash = hash * 23 + ImportantProperty3.GetHashCode();
           hash = hash * 23 + ImportantProperty4.GetHashCode();
           return hash;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Optionally override the `==` and `!=` operators. Unless these are overridden they will default reference equality. See the linked article for an example.

Here's my example in full:

```
namespace ValueEquality
{

    class MyClass : IEquatable<MyClass>
    {
        public int ImportantProperty1 { get; set; }
        public int ImportantProperty2 { get; set; }
        public int ImportantProperty3 { get; set; }
        public int ImportantProperty4 { get; set; }
        public int NonImportantProperty { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(MyClass other)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
                return true;    

            return
                (!Object.ReferenceEquals(this, null)) &&
                (this.ImportantProperty1 == other.ImportantProperty1) &&
                (this.ImportantProperty2 == other.ImportantProperty2) &&
                (this.ImportantProperty3 == other.ImportantProperty3) &&
                (this.ImportantProperty4 == other.ImportantProperty4);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return this.Equals(obj as MyClass);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + ImportantProperty1.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + ImportantProperty2.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + ImportantProperty3.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + ImportantProperty4.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass a = new MyClass() { };
            MyClass b = new MyClass() { };
            if (a.Equals(b))
                Console.WriteLine("a and b are equal");
        }
    }
}
```